# Why doesn't type inference come to the rescue in the case of a swift function with multiple uniquely typed default parameters?

Tags: swift, type-inference, overloading, default-parameters

Consider the following method signature:

```
func doSomething(_ boolToConsider: Bool = false, _ stringToConsider: String? = nil)
```

Calling this method in the following way results in an error:

```
doSomething("foo")
```

[image: error message]

Why doesn't Swift recognize that I intend it to use the default `boolToConsider` and the supplied `stringToConsider`?

Comment: Have you tried to use an external names of the function parameters? Also you can use two functions, one will receive Boolean, the second- String and then make third function to do some common stuff for both

Answer (score 2):

As already mentioned by @Woof you can accomplish what you want providing 3 different method signatures and only one of them, can have all parameters set with default values otherwise it will complain about ambiguous use of your method:

```
func doSomething(_ bool: Bool) {
    print("bool:", bool)
}
func doSomething(_ string: String) {
    print("string:", string)
}
func doSomething(_ bool: Bool = false, _ string: String = "") {
    print("bool:", bool)
    print("string:", string)
}
```

---

```
doSomething(true)
doSomething("foo")
doSomething()
doSomething(true, "foo")
```

---

This will print

> doSomething with bool value only
>
> bool: true
>
> doSomething with string value only
>
> string: foo
>
> doSomething with default values
>
> bool: false
>
> string: default
>
> doSomething with default values
>
> bool: true
>
> string: foo

Answer (score 1):

I don't know why the authors of Swift don't support that or if they ever plan on supporting it. I can speculate that it leads to fairly confusing code to have type based inference of what parts of an argument list were passed.

You can just overload your function.

```
func doSomething(_ stringToConsider: String) {
  doSomething(false, stringToConsider)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Type inference does not work for your example because all of your external parameter labels are anonymous (_). Giving `doSomething` at least one parameter label will fix that.
[image]